# Side effects of setting gl.depthFunc(gl.ALWAYS)

Tags: webgl

Writing a web gl 3D map application. At large zoom out, I experience unavoidle z-fighting. For close zoom very little z-fighting is experienced on Chrome/Firefox, but on Edge / Safari more or less allways present.

Discovered that changing `depthFunc` to `gl.ALWAYS` eliminates the problem on Edge (have not yet tested on Safari).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/depthFunc

My experience when testing gives that the `depthFunc` parameter, can have a huge effect and as I understand the `depthFunc` parameter is a tradeoff. So concerned of strange side effects. Setting to `gl.ALWAYS`, what unwanted effects could occur?

Comment: It will cause many overdraw because each fragments will always get written to frame buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially disabling depth testing doing this, you could just aswell call `gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)`(and while at it create your context without a depth buffer by passing `depth: false` during context creation).

By disabling depth testing your rendering becomes order dependent,
so whatever you draw last will be on top of everything rendered before it, no matter its projection. The same goes for individual triangles in a mesh which will become a problem if you have non-convex geometry or disable backface culling. As already pointed out in the comments another caveat is that *every* fragment is completely processed no matter if it'll be obscured or not.

I would suggest to look into other ways to mitigate z-fighting, from optimizing your view volume to using polygon offset to alternative z-buffer encodings there is a wide variety of approaches to choose from.

Comment: This answer hit the nail. I was misled of much more z-fighting in Edge than Chrome. As suggested in the answer the problem were view volume. Near in the perspective had an unnecessary low value. Correcting this, eliminates the z-fighting totally, even from Edge. Actually when more items were added to the plot,  `gl.ALWAYS` mess up the plotting, now using `gl.LESS`.